# FizzBuzz Function not getting past not a number logic

Tags: javascript, fizzbuzz

I put together a fizzbuzz algorithm and for some odd reason the part of the function that should return "not a number" when the value assigned to the input seems to take every input and return "not a number"  If I keep the if statement with the NaN at the top of the function, nothing gets by it.  If I put it before the return input, the function will run fine if I put a # divisible by 3 or 5, or both, but once it hits the NaN logic, it stop and console logs Not a number.  I'm sure I'm making an obvious mistake, but I can't see it. Can anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKF3Y.jpg)

Comment: Please post code as text, not as image.

Answer (score 0):

You just written condition checks in reverse

```js
function fizzBuzz(input) {
    if (typeof input !== 'number') {
        return 'Not a number';
    }
    if ((input % 3 === 0) && (input % 5 === 0)) {
        return 'FizzBuzz';
    }
    if (input % 3 === 0) {
        return 'Fizz';
    }
    if (input % 5 === 0) {
        return 'Buzz';
    }
    return input;
};

const output = fizzBuzz();
console.log(output);
```